# Cannot install via Homebrew nor Git installer

Tags: macos, git, homebrew

I'm on Mac 10.9.4.

I have Git version 1.8.5.2.

I want to upgrade to latest stable verson of Git (2.0.1 or 2.1?)

I don't know how Git initially was installed on my computer.

When I try with Homebrew I get the following message: "Error: git not installed".

When trying to run `uninstall.sh` from the official Git installer (appearantly I have to uninstall) I get the following message: "Git doesn't appear to be installed via this installer.  Aborting"

Comment: `git` 1.8.5.2 is already installed on OS X in `/usr/bin` and you should leave it there, but you can install the Homebrew `git` 2.x in `/usr/local/bin` and set your `PATH` accordingly.

Comment: Could/should I unistall the included installation? I'd much rather go with Homebrew and don't like the idea to have separate installs.

Comment: No - leave the default git in place, and put any newer version in `/usr/local/bin`. If you set your `PATH` sensibly then everything will just work as expected, and it won't break every time you do an OS update.

Comment: Note: use `brew doctor` to check your current installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The git you have the pre-installed osx git.
Notice that when you run 'git --version' you get: 'git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)'.
You can just run the git installer...

```
brew install git
$ git --version
git version 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)

$ which git
/usr/bin/git

// doh! osx's pre-installed git trumps the brew one, so:
$ sudo mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git-apple

--RUN THE GIT INSTALLER

$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git

$ git --version
git version 1.8.2

// ok cool.
```